# smallcaps in a matrix, \\ coupled with foreach loop

Tags: macros, matrices, foreach, small-caps

I wanted to make a command which would put all of my text in smallcaps and in a matrix. This is \fmold below. This gave me an error, prompting me to make a foreach loop as seen in \smallcapsify and \fm. What is a good solution? And why don't these two ways of solving this problem work?

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin = .5in]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathtools} 
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xstring}

\newcommand{\smallcapsify}[1]{
        \foreach \x in {#1}{\textsc{\x}\\}}

\newcommand{\fm}[1]{$
    \left[
    \begin{matrix}
        \smallcapsify{#1}
    \end{matrix}
    \right] $}

\begin{document}

\fmold{a\\b\\c}
\smallcapsify{a,b,c}
\fm{a,b,c}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just for fun, without `\foreach` and with a much more general macro.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\matrixify}{O{b}mm}
 {
  \cs_set_protected:Nn \__jackirab_matrixify:n { #3 \\ }
  \begin{#1matrix}
  \clist_map_function:nN { #2 } \__jackirab_matrixify:n
  \end{#1matrix}
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\NewDocumentCommand{\fm}{m}{\matrixify{#1}{\textsc{##1}}}

\begin{document}

$\matrixify{a,b,c}{\textsc{#1}}$
$\fm{a,b,c}$
$\matrixify[p]{a,b,c}{(#1)}$

\end{document}
```

The trailing argument to `\matrixify` is a template, where `#1` stands for the current item.

The optional argument can be empty, `p`, `b` (default), `B`, `v` or `V`, to produce the corresponding fences with the usual `amsmath` convention.

You can define commands in terms of `\matrixify`, like I did with `\fm`; remember that in this case the current item has to be denoted by `##1`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Do it with a token list.  The problem with the OP's approach is that the desired tokens are being "typeset" in the midst of the group shenanigans of the `\foreach` loop.  This way, just save the tokens needed (in a way that will survive outside the `\foreach` loop), and then typeset them afterwards.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin = .5in]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathtools} 
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xstring}

\newtoks\mytoks
\newcommand\addtotoks[1]{\global\mytoks\expandafter{\the\mytoks#1}}
\newcommand\xaddtotoks[1]{\expandafter\addtotoks\expandafter{#1}}

\newcommand{\smallcapsify}[1]{\mytoks{}%
        \foreach \x in {#1}{\xaddtotoks{\expandafter\textsc\expandafter{\x}\\}}%
  \the\mytoks}

\newcommand{\fm}[1]{$
    \left[
    \begin{matrix}
        \smallcapsify{#1}
    \end{matrix}
    \right] $}

\begin{document}

$\begin{pmatrix}a\\b\\c\end{pmatrix}$
$\begin{matrix}\smallcapsify{a,b,c}\end{matrix}$
\fm{a,b,c}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could make all math within the scope of your command default to small caps:

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin = .5in]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathtools} 
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xstring}
\DeclareMathAlphabet {\mathsc}{OT1}{cmr}{m}{sc}


\newcommand{\fm}[1]{$
    \left[
    \mathsc{\everymath\expandafter{\expandafter\fam\the\fam\relax}\begin{matrix}#1\end{matrix}}    
    \right]$}

\begin{document}

\fm{a,b,c,A,B,C}

\end{document}
```